# Is there are more elegant way to walk template nesting?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm trying to access a parents data context

To get to it, I have a line that looks like :-

```
template.view.parentView.parentView.parentView.parentView.dataVar.curValue
```

Which in terms of UI, I have

template[dataIwant]  renders another template with a modal dialog which uses autoform

I then use an autoform hook to get a before save event,  which I want to use to add an extra value to the document being saved.

I then walk the template that's passed in the hook back to the top template.  Seems like I should be able to do this in a more elegant way?

Comment: I wish there was a better way for templates to directly communicate with each other. We do things like: `Blaze.getView(el).templateInstance().someVar` where `el` is a DOM node found via a combination of class name and [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/). This is hardly elegant, but possibly better than knowing the precise number of steps between the respective templates.

Comment: I was thinking I could make a tree walker where I could do something like template.getParent('mytemplate').  Was kind of hoping with my question it already existed, or something similar :)

Answer (score 1):

Came up with this code today because I needed it also :

```
_.extend(Blaze.View.prototype,{
  closest: function(searchedViewName){
    currentView = this;
    while (currentView && currentView.name != searchedViewName){
      currentView = currentView.parentView;
    }
    return currentView;
  }
});

<template name="parent">
  {{> child}}
</template>

Template.parent.created = function(){
  this.reactiveVar = new ReactiveVar(false);
};

<template name="child">
  {{parentName}}
  {{parentVar}}
</template>


Template.child.helpers({
  parentName:function(){
    return Template.instance().view.closest("parent").name;
  },
  parentVar:function(){
    return Template.instance().view.closest("parent")._templateInstance.reactiveVar.get();
  }
});
```

So far so good, but I've already spotted use cases where this won't work (using Template.contentBlock in your template definition is breaking the whole thing for some unknown reason).